# How to install a specific debian package

Tags: apt, package-management, version

I want to install a particular version which is not available from `apt-get`
utility but is available from https://packages.debian.org (like https://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/exfat-fuse for instance)

How should I proceed and what are the risks?

Is compiling the source package the only way?

Comment: How do I find out the reason I get a downvote ?

Comment: @Alain you don't, it's one of the ways this site (and humanity) works. It is just poor communication skills.

Comment: @Christopher, I did not come across that page.  Your answer and the one below resolves this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some software projects provide pre-compiled binaries for several distributions.  For Debian, look for a `.deb` package. If you find one, just run:

```
dpkg -i your-package-name.deb
```

Look also: http://backports.debian.org/Instructions

Comment: From the repository in the question, is there any risk of using the package exfat-fuse 1.0.1*, I cannot tell if it is unstable, experimental, ... ?  It is not available from the apt-get utility !

Comment: This answer and the page proposed by @Christopher answers fully this question.

Answer (score 1):

The directory `wheezy-backports` contains packages from Debian testing, recompiled for Debian wheezy. These packages are called [backports](http://backports.debian.org/). They are not part of the default distribution, they are provided as optional extras for users who want newer version of some software. If you have a wheezy system, add backports to your list of packages sources:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main
```

in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list`, then run `apt-get update` then `apt-get install exfat-fuse`.

You can also download a package directly and install it with `dpkg -i FILENAME.deb`. This is not recommended because you will not get any automatic security upgrades for it, and you'll need to take care of any dependency manually.

Comment: apt-get update ==> W: GPG error: http://http.debian.net squeeze-backports Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available...

Comment: @Alain Oops, should be `wheezy-backports`. IIRC since wheezy you don't need to install another key for the backports because the backports have been made official and are signed with the same key as the main distribution.

Comment: apt-get update (with last correction) ==> `Err http://http.debian.net wheezy-backports/main armhf Packages                                                              
  404  Not Found ... W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian-backports/dists/wheezy-backports/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found`

Comment: @Alain Oops, backports also moved from `debian-backports` to `debian` when it became official. Also beware that you have spurious zero-width spaces in your URL.

Comment: Still with same first error `apt-get update ==> W: GPG error:`.  Something is broken in there.  Finally I have got the package from the google forum and installed it with `dpk -i`.  Thx for your time.